# How to filter cscope output within Vim

Tags: vim, cscope

I am looking for a way to grep the output of `cscope` queries from Vim.

The following didn't work for me:

```
:cs f s symbol !grep pattern
```

It gave:

```
E259: no matches found for cscope query s symbol !grep pattern ...
```

P.S:
I know the `redir` method, I am looking for a simpler way to filter
output of ex command(s) through Unix commands.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `:redir` to send message output to a register or file.

```
redir @c
cs f s symbol
redir END
```

Now you can put the `c` register into a file and filter it.

I don't get much output from cscope (it's all in the quickfix), but that will do what you're describing.

---

In general, you can filter shell commands (see `:help :!cmd`) with `|` (bar):

```
:!echo 0updateView | cscope -dl | grep global
```

But ex commands interpret bar as a command separator (so you can put multiple commands on one line):

```
:if &ft != 'help' | silent! cd %:p:h | endif
```

I don't think you can filter the output of ex commands aside from using `redir`. However, you could use Benoit's answer to filter the quickfix.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my functions and macros to filter the quickfix list:

Usage:

- `_qf`, `_qF`, `_qp` and `_qP` will open a dialog prompt
- You will type a Vim pattern into that dialog prompt
- `_qf` and `_qF` will filter on file names, `_qp` and `_qP` on line contents
- capitalized versions have a `:v` effect (keep lines not matching), normal versions keep lines matching your pattern.
- With `:colder` and `:cnewer` you can jump through older and newer quickfix lists if the results do not satisfy you. I have mappings to call those commands, too.

The code:

```
" Filter Quickfix list
function! FilterQFList(type, action, pattern)
    let s:curList = getqflist()
    let s:newList = []
    for item in s:curList
        if a:type == 'f'     " filter on file names
            let s:cmpPat = bufname(item.bufnr)
        elseif a:type == 'p' " filter on line content (pattern)
            let s:cmpPat = item.text . item.pattern
        endif
        if item.valid
            if a:action == '-'
                " Delete matching lines
                if s:cmpPat !~ a:pattern
                    let s:newList += [item]
                endif
            elseif a:action == '+'
                " Keep matching lines
                if s:cmpPat =~ a:pattern
                    let s:newList += [item]
                endif
            endif
        endif
    endfor
    " Assing as new quickfix list
    call setqflist(s:newList)
endfunction

nnoremap _qF            :call FilterQFList('f', '-', inputdialog('Delete from quickfix files matching: ', ''))<CR>
nnoremap _qf            :call FilterQFList('f', '+', inputdialog('Keep only quickfix files matching: ', ''))<CR>
nnoremap _qP            :call FilterQFList('p', '-', inputdialog('Delete from quickfix lines matching: ', ''))<CR>
nnoremap _qp            :call FilterQFList('p', '+', inputdialog('Keep only quickfix lines matching: ', ''))<CR>
```

Comment: Did not work for me. I have also `:set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-,a- `. Actually I can call this function with `:call  FilterQFList`, but the key mapping just do not work. I mean this mapping can work on normal mode before I search anything with cscope. Also I build my vim with `huge` feature.